# Why did the warlocks of Qarth try to engage Daenerys in Astapor?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why did the warlocks of Qarth try to

> assassinate Daenerys in Astapor?

It could only have been done out of spite?

> Would a dead Daenerys ever be useful to them?

Comment: Idk man if someone burnt down my House, I'd be pretty pissed too.

Comment: P.s. Did she burn down House of the undying in show? Or was it just Pyat Pree she killed? Either way, Warlocks are justified in seeking vengeance.

Comment: As I recall, Varys killed Pyat Pree?

Comment: @Aegon Dany and the dragons ended-up being chained inside the House of the Undying. Pyat Pree told her she'd be chained forever. But, he forgot to muzzle the dragons, so he got roasted. Then Dany and the dragons became back outside with Mormont. Other than the assassination attempt, the warlock story ended. I was disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any direct clues - but why wouldn't they have the same motivation they had when they snared Dany in the first place?

They mentioned that the presence of the dragons made their magic stronger (before, they'd been mocked for using mere "parlour tricks" if I remember right). They trapped Dany because they wanted to keep the dragons around - but they discovered the hard way that Dany could order the dragons and that they seemed to protect her.

Kill her, and the newly orphaned dragons would presumably be easier to steal and re-train.

It would make sense that after attempt one fails, and they see what Dany does to Astapor, they'd rethink, and presumably decide that parlour tricks aren't so bad after all.

---

Or, (speculation alert) perhaps they would decide that they could find another way to keep close to the dragons, by using their disguise ability to join Dany's company, build their powers and watch and wait for the right moment...?

Comment: I hope you are correct. The warlocks were the only ones who separated Dany from all the dragons. I interpreted them as huge set-back, that the warlocks were a major foe. But, that storyline went quickly and gently into that good night.